# Unable to install g++ on Ubuntu 14.04 (x64)

Tags: 14.04, g++

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to install g++ for development but every time I try to install g++ using

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

I get the following error. Kindly help me in resolving this issue. Thanks.

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to install g++ and everything it needs to work, you should install `build-essential` package, not g++ alone.  I additionally recomend QtCreator as IDE.
Your problem with apt-get will likely be resolved by doing

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured that something was wrong with updates coming from local server of Ubuntu so I changed it from **/etc/apt/source.list** to Main server and then used **build-essential** to build all necessary components including g++.
Thanks for help @Barafu.

Comment: Next time you should change mirror from System Settings - Software and Updates - Download from: tab. My default country mirror was broken too, so I had to select exact one.